# List all queries of all reports of a specific ORACLE APEX application

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

I know there are some views (example APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_RPT) where you can list diferent objects/items of your APEX apps, but i want to list all queries present in all reports (all types of reports) of my Application, does anyone know how can I list them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer, all the queries are in the column "region_source" in the view "apex_application_page_regions"